# How to calculate difference in time between variable rows in R?

Tags: r, data.table, difftime

I am looking to calculate differences in time for different groups based on beginning work times and end work times. How can I tell R to calculate difftime between two rows based on their labels couched in a group? Below is a sample data set:

```
library(data.table)


latemail <- function(N, st="2012/01/01", et="2012/02/01") {
  st <- as.POSIXct(as.Date(st))
  et <- as.POSIXct(as.Date(et))
  dt <- as.numeric(difftime(et,st,unit="sec"))
  ev <- sort(runif(N, 0, dt))
  rt <- st + ev

}

#create our data frame
set.seed(42)
dt = latemail(20)
work = setDT(as.data.frame(dt))
work[,worker:= stringi::stri_rand_strings(2, 5)]  
work[,dt:= as.POSIXct(as.character(work$dt), tz = "GMT")]
work[,status:=NA]

#order
setorder(work, worker, dt)

#add work times
work$status[1] = "start"
work$status[5] = "end"
work$status[6] = "start"
work$status[10] = "end"
work$status[11] = "start"
work$status[15] = "end"
work$status[16] = "start"
work$status[20] = "end"
```

table looks like this now:

```
                    dt worker status
 1: 2012-01-04 23:11:31  VOuRp  start
 2: 2012-01-09 15:53:16  VOuRp     NA
 3: 2012-01-15 02:56:45  VOuRp     NA
 4: 2012-01-16 21:12:26  VOuRp     NA
 5: 2012-01-20 16:27:31  VOuRp    end
 6: 2012-01-22 15:34:05  VOuRp  start
 7: 2012-01-23 15:01:18  VOuRp     NA
 8: 2012-01-29 03:36:56  VOuRp     NA
 9: 2012-01-29 20:11:02  VOuRp     NA
10: 2012-01-31 02:48:01  VOuRp    end
11: 2012-01-04 10:24:38  u8zw5  start
12: 2012-01-08 17:02:20  u8zw5     NA
13: 2012-01-14 23:33:35  u8zw5     NA
14: 2012-01-15 12:23:52  u8zw5     NA
15: 2012-01-18 03:53:15  u8zw5    end
16: 2012-01-21 03:48:08  u8zw5  start
17: 2012-01-23 02:01:10  u8zw5     NA
18: 2012-01-26 12:51:10  u8zw5     NA
19: 2012-01-29 18:23:46  u8zw5     NA
20: 2012-01-29 22:22:14  u8zw5    end
```

Answer I'm looking for:
ultimately I would like to get the bottom values (labeled worker 1 and worker 2 just because wasn't sure how to do the parallel of `set.seed()` for stringi). The following code gives me the first row for worker 1, but I'd like each shift for each worker:

```
difftime(as.POSIXct("2012-01-20 16:27:31"), as.POSIXct("2012-01-04 23:11:31"), units = "hours")
    Work time   time difference in hours  
    worker 1         377.2667 hours
    worker 2         . . . .
```

In this example I have an even set of values between workers, but assuming I have variable rows between different workers what would that look like? I'm assuming some sort of difftime formula? I would perfer a data table solution as I am working with large data.

Comment: how do you get such numbers? (172.6158 and 388.6102). For me it is not clear what do you want to get.

Comment: I'm sorry, I miscalculated. I am looking for the difference of every end from every start so for example: difftime(as.POSIXct("2012-01-20 16:27:31"), as.POSIXct("2012-01-04 23:11:31"), units = "hours") for worker 1's first shift and then the same for the next shift

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a solution using `data.table`:

```
 work[status %in% c("start", "end"), 
        time.diff := ifelse(status == "start", 
        difftime(shift(dt, fill = NA, type = "lead"), dt, units = "hours"), NA), 
        by = worker][status == "start", sum(time.diff), worker]
```

we get:

```
 worker       V1
1:  VOuRp 580.4989
2:  u8zw5 540.0453
>
```

where `V1` has the sum of all hours from start-end interval for each worker.

Let's explain it step by step for better understanding.

**STEP 1.** Select all rows with `start` or `end` status:

```
work.se <- work[status %in% c("start", "end")]

                    dt worker status
1: 2012-01-04 23:11:31  VOuRp  start
2: 2012-01-20 16:27:31  VOuRp    end
3: 2012-01-22 15:34:05  VOuRp  start
4: 2012-01-31 02:48:01  VOuRp    end
5: 2012-01-04 10:24:38  u8zw5  start
6: 2012-01-18 03:53:15  u8zw5    end
7: 2012-01-21 03:48:08  u8zw5  start
8: 2012-01-29 22:22:14  u8zw5    end
>
```

**STEP 2**: Create a function for calculating the time differences between the current row and the next one. This function will be invoked inside the `data.table` object. We use the `shift` function from the same package:

```
getDiff <- function(x) {
    difftime(shift(x, fill = NA, type = "lead"), x, units = "hours")
}
```

`getDiff` computes the time difference from the next record (within the group) and the current one. It assigns `NA` for the last row because there is no next value. Then we exclude the `NA` values from the calculation.

**STEP 3**: Invoke it within the `data.table` syntax:

```
work.result <- work.se[, time.diff := ifelse(status == "start", 
    getDiff(dt), NA), by = worker]
```

we get this:

```
                    dt worker status time.diff
1: 2012-01-04 23:11:31  VOuRp  start  377.2667
2: 2012-01-20 16:27:31  VOuRp    end        NA
3: 2012-01-22 15:34:05  VOuRp  start  203.2322
4: 2012-01-31 02:48:01  VOuRp    end        NA
5: 2012-01-04 10:24:38  u8zw5  start  329.4769
6: 2012-01-18 03:53:15  u8zw5    end        NA
7: 2012-01-21 03:48:08  u8zw5  start  210.5683
8: 2012-01-29 22:22:14  u8zw5    end        NA
```

**STEP 4**: Sum the non-`NA` values for `time.diff` column for each worker:

```
> work.result[status == "start", sum(time.diff), worker]
   worker       V1
1:  VOuRp 580.4989
2:  u8zw5 540.0453
>
```

`data.table` object can be concatenated via `[]` appended, therefore it can be consolidated into one single sentence for the last part:

```
work.se[, time.diff := ifelse(status == "start", 
    getDiff(dt), NA), by = worker][status == "start", sum(time.diff), worker]
```

**FINAL**: Putting all together into one single sentence:

```
work[status %in% c("start", "end"), 
    time.diff := ifelse(status == "start", 
    difftime(shift(dt, fill = NA, type = "lead"), dt, units = "hours"), NA), 
    by = worker][status == "start", sum(time.diff), worker]
```

Check this [link](https://s3.amazonaws.com/assets.datacamp.com/img/blog/data+table+cheat+sheet.pdf) for `data.table` basic syntax.
I hope this would help, please let us know if it is what you wanted

Comment: Thanks David! This makes sense with the first version of the dataset. I'm wondering though how I might approach my edited version? Where there are two or more sets of starts and ends for each driver?

Comment: This was extremely helpful and exactly what I needed. Thanks David!

Comment: When I try to run the function )`getDiff <- function(x) {
    difftime(shift(x, fill = NA, type = "lead"), x, units = "hours")
}`, I get the error: `Error in shift(x, fill = NA, type = "lead") : object 'x' not found`